# im trying to make a random word generator, why wont it update html after i added a switch to convert numbers to text?

Tags: javascript, html

```
   <ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
for (i = 0; i =5 ; i++;) { 
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 46) + 1)
switch(y) {
    case 1: x="a"; break; case 2: x="i"; break;
  case 3: x="u"; break;  case 4: x="e"; break;
  case 5: x="o"; break; //vowels
  case 6: x="ka"; break; case 7: x="ki"; break;
  case 8: x="ku"; break;  case 9: x="ke"; break;
  case 10: x="ko"; break; //k's
  case 11: x="sa"; break; case 12: x="shi"; break; 
  case 13: x="su"; break;  case 14: x="se"; break;
  case 15: x="so"; break; //s's
  case 16: x="ta"; break;  case 17: x="chi"; break;
  case 18: x="tsu"; break;  case 19: x="te"; break;
  case 20: x="to"; break; //t's
  case 21:x="na"; break;   case 22:x="ni"; break;
  case 23:x="nu"; break;    case 24:x="ne"; break;
  case 25:x="no"; break;//n's
  case 26:x="ha"; break;   case 27:x="hi"; break;
  case 28:x="hu"; break;    case 29:x="he"; break;
  case 30:x="ho"; break;//h's
  case 31:x="ma"; break;   case 32:x="mi"; break;
  case 33:x="mu"; break;    case 34:x="me"; break;
  case 35:x="mo"; break;//m's
  case 36:x="ya"; break;   case 37:x="yu"; break;
  case 38:x="yo"; break;//y's
  case 39: x="ra"; break;  case 40: x="ri"; break; 
  case 41: x="ru"; break;   case 42: x="re"; break; 
  case 43: x="ro"; break;//r's
  case 44: x="wa"; break;  case 45: x="wo"; break;
  case 46: x="n"; break;//w's & n
     default: x="?"; break;
}

   var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);}

}
</script>
```

i put the JavaScript in script tags because the code i used as a reference point didn't work otherwise.
it worked well when i had everything but the for loop and the switch.
i was planing on bodging a chunk of code on js fiddle to generate random text to practice translating into a different script. (i generate 5 chunks at a time, write it down, move on to the next bit of code)
i tried fiddling around with the switch and loop and fixed some semicolon errors but it still doesn't work. any ideas where i messed up? 
edit: please don't edit my code on here, i have to put the script in the html otherwise it gets a error because it for some reason cant find the function. if you have a idea on how to fix that error please let me know

Comment: Your code will be infinite loop, `for (i = 0; i = 5; i++)`

Comment: what do you mean by infinite loop? also, woops my bad

Comment: for loop needs to be terminated based on condition, like when `for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)` . Here loop exits when value of i becomes 5.

Comment: welp, that what i get for not reviewing that kind of stuff after a long break from codeing. make that a answer so i can approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have a syntax error, your console is telling you that. `i++;)` should be `i++)`
2. You have an infinite loop. `for (i = 0; i = 5; i++)` This is assigning 5 to i at every loop, so it will always be true.
3. Bonus : for a much simpler and cleaner code, you could use (I didn't do it all here because it would take too long) :

   `var letters = ["a", "i", "se", "shi"], // etc.
          y = Math.floor((Math.random() * letters.length),
          x = letters[y]; // Job done!`

```js
var letters = ["a", "i", "se", "shi", "ke"] // Just add stuff here.

function myFunction() {
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * letters.length)),
   x = letters[y],
   node = document.createElement("LI"),
   textnode = document.createTextNode(x);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
 }
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after the increment declaration as pointed by Kaddath, and you'll have an infinite loop : `for (i = 0; i = 5; i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++)`